# Widget "Group" not working with "Filter" on Tablesorter

Tags: tablesorter

When I try to use the Filter widget on my table, the Group stops collapsing.

I made 2 test tables.
The "Group" is under SERVIDOR

http://stats.wotpt.tk/WOTPT_Filter_Off.php

with `widgets               : ['group', 'zebra', 'math', 'cssStickyHeaders'],`

http://stats.wotpt.tk/WOTPT_Filter_On.php

with `widgets               : ['group', 'filter', 'zebra', 'math', 'cssStickyHeaders'],`

This is the only difference between the tables.

On WOTPT_Filter_Off.php the Groups collapses, but they are not visible on page load. The table needs to be reordered to display the Groups.

On WOTPT_Filter_Off.php the Groups are shown at page load but they do not collapse.

I'm using: Tablesorter by Rob Garrison (Mottie) 2.20.1 and Jquery 1.11.2.

Comment: This demo http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/2054/ has the same problem: The groups don`t collapse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That problem turned out to be a bug in the filter widget. It was adding a "display:table-row" to every visible row so the "group-hidden" class was not able to hide the collapsed group.

I've fixed this problem in the latest version (v2.21.0) - The [grouping widget demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-grouping.html) now includes a filter row for testing ;P

Thanks for reporting this issue!